# How to create Common Code in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am writing three applications (with 1 module each) in Zend Framework 2 that eventually come together as a unified portal with same look and feel. I plan to write some common code that can be shared between these three apps.

Ex: Couple of classes to programatically create a datagrid, Couple of classes to programatically create a form, etc..

Can you suggest an ideal location to put all this code, so I can just plug and play in my modules when required?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module with all the common code in the src folder, `PortalCommon/src/PortalCommon` for instance. You can then let the 3 modules depend on that module:

```
namespace Module1;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\DependencyIndicatorInterface;

class Module implements DependencyIndicatorInterface
{   
    public function getModuleDependencies()
    {
        return array('PortalCommon');   
    }

    ...
}
```

Another option is to create a module for all the common functionality. So in your case you might get a datagrid module and a form module.

Comment: So, if I create a Datagrid Module and Form Module, will these go in the vendor directory? Also, where will the CSS and JS for these modules will go?

Comment: The idea is to create a git repo called "common" and put the datagrid and form module there, so all my applications can just download the repo and plug and play

Comment: The [assetic module](https://github.com/widmogrod/zf2-assetic-module) has been created to allow for assets (JS/CSS/etc.) management.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate module : `Jake\Common` or `Jake\Core` in a git repo.

Register this repo on Packagist or on a personnal [Satis instance](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) if it is private.

You can then include it as a dependency in your `composer.json` and it will be downloaded in `vendor`.